# how to compare two NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsmutablearray

How can I compare two NSMutableArray ? if both are same than it should return true otherwise false.

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two NSMutableArrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332971/how-to-compare-two-nsmutablearrays)

Comment: @nyuszika7h : please check the question's date ! :)

Comment: Well, I tried to improve a suggested edit for this and it told me a question with that title already exists, so there's that. I didn't realize this one is older, though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
return ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]);
```

returns `YES` if arrays are equal else returns `NO`

Comment: -1 from me. you have a couple of problems. 1)the method already returns a BOOL YES or NO, so there is to need to test for the BOOL and return the same thing. 2)BOOL in Objective-C is `YES` and `NO` not `true` or `false`. It will compile - but it's not a Cocoa convention.

Comment: @Abizern: +1! Thanks, I will edit my answer. I made it a test so that a noob user can get the idea better.

Comment: Sorry - poor style is poor style. Using a method to call a method and just return it's result?

Comment: @Abizern: Yes i know, modified it again. :)

Comment: Why are you returning a value that is already being returned?

Answer (score 9):

Does [`isEqualToArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/isEqualToArray%3a) method help you?

Other way is to iterate through both arrays and compare each object using [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a)  method. It is the same to calling `isEqualToArray:`. Note that in both variants you should implement `isEqual:` method in your array object class if it in not a standard class.

And right before this operations you can just compare their length, if they are not equal so there is no point of spending resources on more complicated calculations.

Comment: -1. The first part is okay - I think you're explanation is wrong. It's usually better to to use the particular `isEqualTo<class>` methods rather than the general `isEqual` method. Particarly as in this for arrays it first checks the lengths for you and then compares each of the objects.

Comment: I've mentioned just another way of comparison of objects (it could be useful). I've referred it as _other_ way. In the third part I've mentioned array length comparison. Surely, it deserves minus, my bad.

Comment: If user don't want to compare the whole object, it's much better to implement `isEqual:`. What if we compare apples only by size and color? We don't need to know how much seeds inside the apple. Hope you've got it

Comment: `isEqualToArray` does an array length comparison anyway - why would you want to write a test for length and then test for equality if it's true. Yes, it may be another way, but it isn't a very good way.

Answer (score 6):

Use isEqualToArray: method to compare between two array object

like this :

Method 1:

```
return [array1 isEqualToArray:array2]; //return YES or NO
```

Method 2:

```
if([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]) {//perform condition on YES}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[array1 isEqualToArray:array2];
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be able to use the `NSArray` base class to compare one array with another array:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]){

   }else{

   }
```

Comment: It would be good to provide a link to method documentation or add comments on how method does the comparison.