# How to compare two NSMutableArrays?

Tags: iphone, ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray, compare

I'm new to iOS development and having trouble comparing two `NSMutableArray`.

One of them (`appDelegate.array` in code) contains data coming from a database and another one (`dataArray` in code) contains data coming from a server response.

Now I want compare each element of (`dataArray`) with whole (`appDelegate.array`) and if some element of (`dataArray`) exist in (`appDelegate.array`) then do nothing or break and if doesn't exist then add it into database.

I tried, but am unable to do this. Below is the code I'm using.

Thank you in advance.

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"myDATA"];

NSLog(@"%d dataArray count", [dataArray count]);

    for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++)
    {   
        NSLog(@"%d delegate array count",[appDelegate.array count]);

        NSInteger ID = [[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"] intValue];
        NSString *Note = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Note"];
        NSString *Reminder = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Reminder"];
        NSInteger Status = [[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Completed"]intValue];
        NSInteger DisplayOrder = [[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Display_Order"] intValue];

        if ([appDelegate.array count] == 0 && Note != nil) 
        {
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Tasks (Note, Reminder, Status, DisplayOrder) VALUES ('%@','%@','%d','%d')",Note, Reminder, Status, DisplayOrder];

            //NSLog(@"%@",query);
            sqlite3 *database_1;

            NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *database_Path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TODO.sqlite"];

            if(sqlite3_open([database_Path UTF8String], &database_1) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement_1;
                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_1,[query UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement_1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement_1) == SQLITE_ROW)
                    {
                        sqlite3_step(compiledStatement_1);
                    }
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement_1);
            }
            sqlite3_close(database_1);

            [self readDataFromDatabase];
        }

        else 
        {
           // NSLog(@"Entered Else");

            for (int k = 0; k < [appDelegate.array count]; k++) 
            {


            objectData = [appDelegate.array objectAtIndex:k];
              //  NSLog(@"%d",objectData.ID);

                NSMutableArray *IDArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[[NSNumber numberWithChar:objectData.ID]stringValue]];
                NSMutableArray *NoteArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:objectData.Note];
                NSMutableArray *ReminderArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:objectData.Reminder];
                NSMutableArray *StatusArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[[NSNumber numberWithChar:objectData.Status]stringValue]];
                NSMutableArray *DisplayOrderArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[[NSNumber numberWithChar:objectData.DisplayOrder]stringValue]];

                NSLog(@"%@ server",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ID]);
                NSLog(@"%@ database",IDArray);

                if ([CommonFunctions isValueInArray:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ID]:IDArray] && [CommonFunctions isValueInArray:Note :NoteArray] && [CommonFunctions isValueInArray:Reminder :ReminderArray] && [CommonFunctions isValueInArray:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Status] :StatusArray] && [CommonFunctions isValueInArray:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",DisplayOrder] :DisplayOrderArray]) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"Present In appDelegate.array!!!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Tasks (Note, Reminder, Status, DisplayOrder) VALUES ('%@','%@','%d','%d')",Note, Reminder, Status, DisplayOrder];

                    NSLog(@"%@",query);
                    sqlite3 *database_1;

                    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *database_Path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TODO.sqlite"];

                    if(sqlite3_open([database_Path UTF8String], &database_1) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement_1;
                        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_1,[query UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement_1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                        {
                            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement_1) == SQLITE_ROW)
                            {
                                sqlite3_step(compiledStatement_1);
                            }
                        }
                        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement_1);
                    }
                    sqlite3_close(database_1);


                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137469/how-to-compare-two-nsmutablearray

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. There might me some small mistake. Can you tell us what's going wrong exactly?

Comment: Is the ID unique? If so, you could make a predicate on appDelegate.array to find all elements which are not in your other array. That is, "take all elements in appDelegate.array for which the ID does not exist in array". Take a look at NSPredicate and maybe the block base method. Now, iterate over the filtered array and store all elements in that array.

Comment: Rushi: I don't know somehow it is not working correctly and add duplicate records in the database...this is banging my head since last two days...!

Comment: Can anyone edit this code for me, please...? I have gone with Anusha's answer but [containsObject:] doesn't work for my case and I need go with another method. In my code if condition is not working and gives unwanted result.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++)
{  
  if ([appDelegate.array count] == 0 && Note != nil) 
  {

  }
  else
  {
    if(![appDelegate.array containsObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]])
    {
      // Your code
    }
    else
    {
     // Do nothing Continue; or Break;
     Continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @roamingsoul I didn't understand.. You wrote this condition inside the for loop no? If condition fails and appDelegate.array contains object continue the loop for next object..

Comment: @roamingsoul With this condition no need of that inner for loop. This condition itself will check that object exist in array or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(ModelClassName *)object
{
    if ([self.ID isEqualToString:object.ID]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Subclass your model object and override isEqual method, then use

```
[array containsObject:] method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]){

   // Equal..
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `[array1 isEqualToArray:array2]` directly? What is the point of having it inside another method? I think OP is looking for the above answer posted by Anusha.

Comment: I was just trying to show that it works with the mutableArray :)

Comment: this only works when the objects at the same indexes are the same: "Two arrays have equal contents if they each hold the same number of objects and objects at a given index in each array satisfy the isEqual: test."